# Show  JS(jQuery) widget on any site, with ASP.NET MVC server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jsonp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show modal JS dialog on any site using button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704350/show-modal-js-dialog-on-any-site-using-button)

I need some  kind of advise, how to use technologies to achieve following functionality:

So, some web-developer place piece of code on his site, like this:

```
 <script src="http://mydomain/Scripts/LoadDialog" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
    <img src="http://mydomain.com/image"
     onclick="window.ShowModalDialog(someArgs, **UserID**);" />
```

When user pressing on image button, there is server call occurs, and depending
on userID server will return content. As a server side technology is planed to use ASP.NET MVC. On front-end side will be JavaScript and jQuery.
Please let me know please if you know how it can be achived or where I can start from.

**NOTE:**  Generally, these code should be placed on a site what user wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the following blog entry, it helped me a great deal while developing something similar

http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/

In general, keywords for you are dynamic javascript and css loading and JSON-P that enables getting around browser's same origin policy while sending AJAX requests.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any expreience with such issue?

Comment: Yes, I do have some experience developing third-party web widgets. Ask, whenever you have some concrete problems, I will gladly help you whenever time allows me to do so. Best

Answer (score 1):

Look at this SO post [jsonP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758879/asp-net-mvc-returning-jsonp) and the ticked answer provides an example of pretty much what it sounds like you want to do (in MVC / Javascript)